# Race condition on Create record MVC 5

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to build an application flow that works like this:

1. User visits a specific page
2. User clicks "Create new blog post"
3. Blog post record in database gets created, with default fields like {Title = "Your Title Goes Here"}
4. User directed to Edit page for that new record, with default fields loaded from DB.

I know this is backwards from the common flow:

1. User visits a specific page
2. User clicks "Create new blog post"
3. User directed to Edit page where they fill in all the info
4. User presses Submit, at which time the blog post record is created

What I'm finding is that in my flow, the record is being created in my BlogPostController, which does a RedirectToAction("Edit"), but the edit page is loading *before* the new record has been committed to the DB, so I am getting error 400 "bad request".

The reason I am flipping around the order is I want a more AJAXy editing experience that doesn't require an explicit "Save" or form submit. So I need to be writing data to the record as the user enters it in.

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: For instance, I want to be able to create a new record and immediately edit its fields on the next page, using something like http://www.codenothing.com/archives/jquery/inline-text-edit/

Comment: How are you saving to the DB, can you can you wait for the result? e.g. Async/Await pattern?, that way you can pass the new Blog recored directly to the Edit action

Comment: Yes, that is what I would like to do. How can I do that?

Comment: depends on your how you are saving to the DB, is it via a webservice or EntityFramework or a simple wrapper like Dapper

Comment: I'm using EntityFramework with the default CRUD pages that you get when you create a new MVC app in VS2013

Comment: Looking at EntityFramework it seems they have async methods, so you should be able to use Async/Await to solve the race condition, I added a quick example below